# SliverList doesn't update when adding or removing an item

Tags: dart, flutter, state, flutter-sliver

This is my code:

```
class HomeCardList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Location location;
  final Position position;

  HomeCardList(this.location, this.position);

  @override
  _HomeCardListState createState() => _HomeCardListState();
}

class _HomeCardListState extends State<HomeCardList> {
  List<Widget> _homeCards = [TimeDateCard(), TimeDateCard()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new LocationAppbar(
          location: widget.location,
          position: widget.position,
        ),
        new SliverList(
          delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(_homeCards),
        ),
        new SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _homeCards.removeLast();
            });
          }),
        ),
        new SliverFixedExtentList(
            delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
              return new Text('Item #$index');
            }),
            itemExtent: 320.0)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When i press the `RaisedButton` it **does** remove the last widget from the list i want to show (if i'll add a `print()` statement i'll see an entry was removed), but doesn't update the state as it should, i can still see 2 widgets. when i press the button the third time i get an exception for trying to remove an item from an empty list.

What am i doing wrong here? Why when i remove a widget from the list, the state doesn't update correctly and show only one widget?

**Edit:**
When i try something like

```
setState(){
    _homeCards = [];
}
```

It does refreshes with an empty list, what's wrong here?

Comment: try calling the list inside `setState` after removing the item, `removeLast()` returns the removed item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `_homeCards` a getter so it's computed lazily, then `setState` will trigger rebuild